# Implement simple Selected effect for Textviews in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I have simple `RecyclerView` that only has `TextViews`, when a textview is selected I would like to have the seleceted textview to change its textcolor to `Color.Yellow` and when it is deselected or an other item is selected the current selected item shall ofcourse change back to the default color `Color.White`

I have tried with a selector drawable like this, which didn't work:

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#fed002" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#fed002" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fed002" />
<item android:color="#fff" />
```

And I have tried with a ColorStateList in my `RecyclerView Adapater`which didn't work too.

It just seem to much complicated for a simple thing.

**My onBindViewHolder just contains a Textview:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getFontName());
    holder.textView.setTypeface(list.get(position).getTypeface());
}
```

Comment: Textview becomes selected when you press on recyclerview item that contains needed textview?

Comment: No it dosn't @Marat

Comment: Then which action makes textview selected?

Comment: @Marat Nothing. I just want that when the user clicks on the list of textview, the clicked one is highlighted